# when i try to use pywhatkit module then this error is coming " from flask import Flask, request ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' "

Tags: python, module, artificial-intelligence

```
File "C:\Users\Rishabh\PycharmProjects\FRIDAY\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pywhatkit
  File "C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywhatkit\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pywhatkit.remotekit import start_server
  File "C:\Users\Rishabh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pywhatkit\remotekit.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your module is trying to import another python package but didn't find it. Try to install the 'flask' module for your environment.
Simply using terminal or cmd(windows) and type in:

```
pip install flask
```

Comment: thank's for helping me but I am just modifying your answer pip3 install flask\